# Login user - opposite to launchctl bootout user/id

Tags: macos, applescript, startup, user-account, login

How can I login user in programmatically way?

I need something opposite to command

> launchctl bootout user/502

that logouts user with id=502.

Does this way exist?

Comment: What are you wanting to do, once the user has logged in?

Comment: Copy some data. Without login this data won't be synchronised to the latest changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Not on macOS

No, there is no Apple supported programmatic way of logging in a user on macOS.

One approach would be to create a virtual smart card and simulate a user logging in. This would require significant effort and development time.

Comment: I found some way. Connect through VNC in AppleScript. It works, but I search for more elegant way...

Comment: That is a clever approach for a computer you control. Be aware that VNC may not be over a secure connection and thus any credentials (username and passphrase) may be at risk.

Comment: That what I need: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/386654/sync-imessage-chat-db-in-mac-without-user-is-logged-in