# Have iMessage chat.db in Mac updated without user being logged in

Tags: mac, data-synchronization, chat

I want to connect (through ssh, for example) to users in different computers and copy their iMessage history (`chat.db`). But this file doesn't get updated while the user isn't logged in.

Is there a way to get message updates while the user is logged out?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I want to connect (through ssh, for example) to users in different computers and copy chat.db. BUT if I do it when a user logged out, file chat.db isn't updated.

Comment: Are you looking for messages received *while* the user is not logged in at all?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for this